# Как объединить много файлов word в 1 конечный с помощью nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ms-word

Пытаюсь объединить но не чего толком не выходит. Пробовал через библиотеку docx-merger, но даже при попытке запустить example примера при открытии готового файла у меня возникает ошибка. Вероятно это происходит из-за того что word у меня 2016 а библиотека 5 лет назад закончила обновляться, но это не точно. Пробовал устанавливать пакеты с node 14, 16, 18, ошибка всегда одна и та же. Кто ни будь сталкивался с такой задачей. Помогите пожалуйста уже 2 дня сижу с мертвой точки сдвинуться не могу. Буду рад любому решению. Прикрепляю файлы которые должны быть сшиты в 1 файл.

[Файлы для сшива](https://dropmefiles.com/zgf6Q)

пароль к архиву 123

Comment: `у меня возникает ошибка` добавьте текст ошибки

Comment: кстати, вы обратили внимание, что библиотека https://www.npmjs.com/package/docx-merger работает с файлами формата `docx`, а в вашем архиве файлы в формате `doc`? наверное вы там как-то выполняете конвертацию, но показать в вопросе стесняетесь?

Comment: При конвертации ошибки нет. Ошибка возникает в момент открытия объединенного файла и звучит она так: К сожалению ну удается открыть файл output.docx из-за проблем с его содержимым. приложение Word в документе output.docx обнаружено содержимое, которое не удалось прочитать. Попробовать восстановить содержимое документа? Если вы доверяете источнику этого документа, нажмите кнопку 'Да'. После нажатия Да высвечивается: К сожалению не удается открыть файл output.docx из за его содержимого.

Comment: По поводу формата сюда я скинул те файлы из которых мне необходимо собрать, но тестирую я просто на docx файлах пока что любых изначально созданных в формате docx, в частности с template.docx и template1.docx из примера в docx-merger, и даже он корректно не работает, выдает ошибки. Конвертировать из doc в docx думаю не самая большая проблема.

Comment: в issues библиотеки действительно есть сообщения об ошибках при открытии сгенерированных файлов. и автор библиотеки не занимается issues-ами. ищите форки библиотеки или другой инструмент

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Единственный путь который нашел и действия корректно выполняют данную задачу это пакет docxcompose на языке python. Адекватного решения для nodejs не нашел и возможно его не существует на данный момент.